# Cannot download archived files from Amazon Glacier using php

Tags: php, amazon-glacier

Am trying to download files from amazon glacier. I have initiated my jobs and have succesfully gotten my **jobId.**

Now am using code below to download my archived uploaded files but am shown this response

```
object(Aws\Result)#129 (2) { 
    ["data":"Aws\Result":private]=> array(8) { 
        ["body"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream)#114 (7) {
            {"stream":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> resource(118) of type (stream) 
            ["size":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> NULL 
            ["seekable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) 
            ["readable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) 
            ["writable":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> bool(true) 
            ["uri":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> string(10) "php://temp" 
            ["customMetadata":"GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream":private]=> array(0) { } } 
            ["checksum"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["status"]=> int(200) 
            ["contentRange"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["acceptRanges"]=> string(5) "bytes" 
            ["contentType"]=> string(16) "application/json" 
            ["archiveDescription"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["@metadata"]=> array(4) { 
                ["statusCode"]=> int(200) 
                ["effectiveUri"]=> string(161) "https://glacier.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/-/vaults/myvault/jobs/my-jobid-removed-for-privacy/output" 
                ["headers"]=> array(5) { 
                    ["x-amzn-requestid"]=> string(47) "AXVtTY2JMZzODN_Yya2c" 
                    ["accept-ranges"]=> string(5) "bytes" 
                    ["content-type"]=> string(16) "application/json" 
                    ["content-length"]=> string(3) "124" 
                    ["date"]=> string(29) "Thu, 15 Aug 2019 14:51:40 GMT" 
                } 
                ["transferStats"]=> array(1) { 
                    ["http"]=> array(1) { 
                        [0]=> array(0) { } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        ["monitoringEvents":"Aws\Result":private]=> array(0) { } 
    }
```

Do I need to set any permission. I s my archive file private. can someone tell me something

**here is the code**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Glacier\GlacierClient;
use Aws\Glacier\TreeHash;


$client = new GlacierClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'my-region',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'my key',
        'secret' => 'my secret'
    ]
]);

$result = $client->getJobOutput([
    'accountId' => '-',
    'jobId' => 'my job id',
    'vaultName' => 'my valt name here', 
]);


var_dump($result);
echo $data = $result->get('body');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that files from Glacier take time to "unfreeze" to become downloadable and available. This is the exact reason why Glacier is so much more cheaper than something like S3.

[Here is a link](https://github.com/pihish/amazon_glacier/blob/master/download_4.php) to an example on how to find out when the files are ready to be downloaded.

Comment: S3 glacier is very funny. It requires patience. Thanks